# Add Comment or Notes Block to top of View?

Tags: sql, oracle

My department frequently puts a comment block at the top of our procedures that explains the basic purpose of the procedure, as well as some modification history and related work order numbers.  I would like to do the same thing with a few new views I am creating.  Is this possible?

I've tried placing the comment block in various spots, before the CREATE OR REPLACE, after it, but it seems like any comment lines above the select are dropped.  We are using Oracle and PL/SQL Developer.

```
/*
PURPOSE
MULTI-LINE COMMENTS
WORK ORDER NUMBERS FOR MODIFICATIONS 
ETC
*/

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SAMPLE_VIEW AS
SELECT     SYSDATE
FROM       DUAL
```

I don't receive any error messages.  The comments are visible in the saved sql file, but not when you right-click and view the view in PL/SQL Developer.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The statement starts at `create`. Anything before that is not part of the view definition and is ignored by the database. (This is the same for procedures or packages: the database ignores comments before the `create or replace` keywords.)

Solution is simple: move the comment text into the view body.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SAMPLE_VIEW AS
    SELECT   
/*
PURPOSE
MULTI-LINE COMMENTS
WORK ORDER NUMBERS FOR MODIFICATIONS 
ETC
*/
      SYSDATE AS DATE1
FROM       DUAL
```

Note the comment must be embedded in the query, after the SELECT keyword, otherwise the compiler will bin it off. Frankly that's bobbins but that's the way it is.

Also, remember that we can add comments about database objects (table or table column, unified audit policy, edition, indextype, materialized view, mining model, operator, or view) using the COMMENT command. This is cleaner than embedding the comment in the query and treats Views like Tables, which seems idiomatic, rather than PL/SQL units. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4010.htm#SQLRF01109).

Comment: Thank you for helping.  I must still be doing something wrong.  I created a view with the following code 

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SAMPLE_VIEW AS
/*
PURPOSE
MULTI-LINE COMMENTS
WORK ORDER NUMBERS FOR MODIFICATIONS 
ETC
*/
SELECT     SYSDATE AS DATE1
FROM       DUAL


but when I then right click and select view ON SAMPLE_VIEW it looks like the following

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SAMPLE_VIEW AS
SELECT     SYSDATE AS DATE1
FROM       DUAL;
MULTI-LINE COMMENTS
WORK ORDER NUMBERS FOR MODIFICATIONS 
ETC
*/
SELECT     SYSDATE AS DATE1
FROM       DUAL

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault for not actually testing it. I have corrected my code but I'm not that impressed.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I was afraid that moving it after the select was the only viable option. I was hoping I was just missing some better option. Sadness :(